# How can I make this into another class and later call it for use during main?

Tags: c#

I want to take this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tSkriv in dina fem ord");
Random rng = new Random();
int index = rng.Next(5);
string[] ordlista = new string[5];
ordlista[0] = Console.ReadLine(); 
ordlista[1] = Console.ReadLine();
ordlista[2] = Console.ReadLine();
ordlista[3] = Console.ReadLine();
ordlista[4] = Console.ReadLine();
```

And make into a separate class so I can first call upon it for a user to input 5 words. Then I also want to be able to call it back for a sorted list of all the words and also call one random word from that list to use in the guessing of a word. How do I go about doing this?
I'm tried searching but I just don't understand any of the similar answers I've found.

Comment: Your current code is not doing what you described. Making it into separate class will not help you. Also have you started writing that class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Words
    {                     
        List<string> ordlista;
        Random rng; 
        public Words()
        {
            ordlista = new List<string>();
        }
        public void AddWord(string s)
        {
            ordlista.Add(s);
        }
        public string GetRandomWord()
        {
            if(rng==null)
                rng = new Random();
            return ordlista[rng.Next(ordlista.Count)];
        }
    }
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Words wordManager = new Words();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tSkriv in dina fem ord");

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            wordManager.AddWord(Console.ReadLine());            
            Console.WriteLine(wordManager.GetRandomWord());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using List, so you can add as many words as you want. You can call wordManager.GetRandomWord() to get a random word. I hope this is a good start. You still need to change the code to do all you want. Good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate it! Will help me greatly in improving my C# skills and understanding.